# Fetch terminal command (Nodejs) and send to specific port via AJAX

Tags: ajax, node.js

I'm actually working on a little application. I have one server written in C which is listening on the port 5260. In the other side I have a NodeJS client which is listening on the port 7777. A HTML page can be reach via this port. In the HTML page I have a simple button.
When I click on this one a message is sent to my NodeJS server and is written on the terminal. Now I would like to fetch this command and send it to my C server which is still running and waiting for a request.

My client.js :

```
var http = require('http');
var ejs = require('ejs');
var express=require('express');

var app = express();

app.engine('html', ejs.renderFile);

app.set('/', __dirname);

app.get('/', function(request,response) {

  response.render('index.ejs.html');
})

var options = {
  host: '192.168.1.154',
  path: '/',
  port: '5260',
  method: 'POST'
};

app.post('/play', function(req, res){
  var res = http.request(options);
  console.log("START_BG;BG1\n");
});

app.listen(7777);
```

And my HTML file :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="client.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

        function sendMessage() {    
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', '/play', true);
            xhr.onload = function() {
             console.log(xhr);
            };
            xhr.send();
        }

      </script>
    </head>
<body>

<button onclick="sendMessage()">VIDEO</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So, do you get an error while running your current code?

Comment: No errors.. In the nodejs terminal I receive the command START_BG;BG1 and in the other terminal windows (where the other server is waiting for a message on the 5260 port) I don't receive nothing....

Comment: I'm not clear; is the C server specifically an HTTP server or is it listening on that port as a raw TCP socket?

Answer (score 0):

Well. I see some strange things in your code

1 You're making the post request to **192.168.1.254:5620/play** without sending any data on it

2 You're not waiting  fro the request to end and blindly print on your console without checking the result. Don't know if its the desired behaviour, but it seems a bit strange

Without more knowledge about the scenario is difficult to suggest an idea.

- What is the answer you expect from the remote server?
- It's suposed to print something in the (remote) console ?
- What it should return via HTTP ?

Anyway I suggest you correct your code as follows:

```
app.post('/play', function(req, res){
  var res = http.request(options, function(response){
    // do any checking about response status and/or body if any
    console.log("START_BG;BG1\n");
  });
});
```

Comment: This isn't an answer, it's a comment.